# JQuery datepicker defaultDate not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

From the JQueryUI website, to set a deafult date:

```
 Specify either an actual date via a Date object or 
 as a string in the current dateFormat
```

I chose the latter, yet the following fails (field is blank) and I have no idea why:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#show_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'DD dd MM yy',
        altField: "#booking_date",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        defaultDate: 'Saturday 02 August 2014'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#show_date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD dd MM yy',
    altField: "#booking_date",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    defaultDate: 'Saturday 02 August 2014'
}).val('Saturday 02 August 2014');
```

Comment: That then bypasses the altField setting so doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what the JQueryUI page says, the simplest solution was to simply add a default date to the field itself:

```
<input class="form-control" value="Saturday 02 August 2014" name="show_date" id="show_date" type="text">
```

I then reverted JQ code to what it was originally:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#show_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'DD dd MM yy',
        altField: "#booking_date",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```